# Why can't I start mysql?

Tags: 20.04, mysql

I am running on Ubuntu 20.04 with MySQL 8 and ever since I ran the command

> Sudo service mysql restart

I receive this in terminal:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Now i run systemctl status mysql.server after that and get:

```
 mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2021-04-18 20:27:01 UTC; 36s ago
    Process: 1133 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCC>
    Process: 1141 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 1141 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"
      Error: 13 (Permission denied)
```

Why is it not restarting? This happens on every ubuntu instance I create. I am on Digital Ocean also.

** ERROR LOG IS EMPTY in /var/log/mysql/ **

Comment: Use `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u mysql`.

Comment: Did you migrated any old data like copying data directory?

Answer (score 2):

This sort of error will happen when the MySQL data directory is not readable by the MySQL user account. If you have moved your data directory or copied the MySQL database files from a different installation, you will need to update the permissions like so:

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

Be sure to replace `/var/lib/mysql` with the proper location of your MySQL data files if you have configured the system to use a different directory.